# python311.dll: file not recognized: File format not recognized

Tags: c++, python-3.x, matplotlib, dll

I'm using MinGW (6.3.0) and Python 3.11. I have a problem compiling [matplotlib-cpp](https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp). In order to compile a simple algorithm, I use the following instruction:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -I C:/Python311/include -I C:/Python311/Lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include -L C:/Python311 -lpython311
```

As output, I have a set of warnings and one error shown hereafter. What can be the problem? Thank you in advance.

```
In file included from main.cpp:8:0:
matplotlibcpp.h: In constructor 'matplotlibcpp::detail::_interpreter::_interpreter()':
matplotlibcpp.h:174:9: warning: 'void Py_SetProgramName(const wchar_t*)' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         Py_SetProgramName(name);
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/Python311/include/Python.h:94:0,
                 from matplotlibcpp.h:5,
                 from main.cpp:8:
C:/Python311/include/pylifecycle.h:37:38: note: declared here
 Py_DEPRECATED(3.11) PyAPI_FUNC(void) Py_SetProgramName(const wchar_t *);
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from main.cpp:8:0:
matplotlibcpp.h:174:31: warning: 'void Py_SetProgramName(const wchar_t*)' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         Py_SetProgramName(name);
                               ^
In file included from C:/Python311/include/Python.h:94:0,
                 from matplotlibcpp.h:5,
                 from main.cpp:8:
C:/Python311/include/pylifecycle.h:37:38: note: declared here
 Py_DEPRECATED(3.11) PyAPI_FUNC(void) Py_SetProgramName(const wchar_t *);
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from main.cpp:8:0:
matplotlibcpp.h:182:9: warning: 'void PySys_SetArgv(int, wchar_t**)' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         PySys_SetArgv(argc, const_cast<wchar_t **>(argv));
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/Python311/include/Python.h:96:0,
                 from matplotlibcpp.h:5,
                 from main.cpp:8:
C:/Python311/include/sysmodule.h:13:38: note: declared here
 Py_DEPRECATED(3.11) PyAPI_FUNC(void) PySys_SetArgv(int, wchar_t **);
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from main.cpp:8:0:
matplotlibcpp.h:182:57: warning: 'void PySys_SetArgv(int, wchar_t**)' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
         PySys_SetArgv(argc, const_cast<wchar_t **>(argv));
                                                         ^
In file included from C:/Python311/include/Python.h:96:0,
                 from matplotlibcpp.h:5,
                 from main.cpp:8:
C:/Python311/include/sysmodule.h:13:38: note: declared here
 Py_DEPRECATED(3.11) PyAPI_FUNC(void) PySys_SetArgv(int, wchar_t **);
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/Python311/python311.dll: file not recognized: File format not recognized
```

I tried to change the library from -lpython311 to -lpython3, but I have the same output. Furthermore, I tried to include the lib path as follows:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -I C:/Python311/include -I C:/Python311/Lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include -L C:/Python311/libs -lpython311
```

I still have the same warnings but a new error is present and depicted as follows:

```
C:/Python311/libs/python311.lib: error adding symbols: File format not recognized
```

Comment: As linked article states, my assumption would be you are trying to link incorrect architecture. Make sure the library and yours are built using the same architecture.

Comment: I recommend using the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), it's likely to make your life much easier. All packages are installed as precompiled binaries. [Package List](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.8_win-64/). **If you are using Anaconda, do not use `pip` to install/remove packages that exist within the `conda` ecosystem.** Use `conda install package`. Only use `pip` if the package is not available with `conda install`. Using `pip` can potentially wreck your installation because `pip` and `conda` do not manage dependencies in the same way.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisMM for the good hint, which solved my problem. I checked the version of mingw, noting that it was 32-bit. To verify it, I tried adding the `-m64` flag during the compilation phase, but that didn't work. Then I installed the 64-bit version of mingw and now it works!